Downloading files in nextjs (axios) and nestjs
I have the following endpoint:
 @ApiGet(':id/download', { type: OutputStatusDto, description: 'Download file from URL' })
  async downloadFile(@User() user: UserEntity, @Param() params: InputIdDto, @Res() res: Response) {
    const file = await this._fileService.findOne({ where: { id: params.id }, relations: { user: true } });
    // /* For now, allow downloading only files that are not assigned to any user */
    // if (user.role !== Roles.ADMIN && file.user && file.user.id !== user.id)
    //   throw new BadRequestException(ErrorMessages.UNAUTHORIZED_ACTION);

    const { buffer } = await this._fileService.downloadFile(file.url);

    res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${file.originalname}`,
      'Content-Length': buffer.length,
    });

    res.end(buffer);
  }


  async downloadFile(url: string): Promise<{ buffer: Buffer }> {
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

    return { buffer: Buffer.from(response.data) };
  }


In my APP I have:
export const useDownloadFile = () => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: downloadFile,
    onSuccess(data) {
      const blob = new Blob([data.data]);

      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = data.filename;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    },
  });
};

export const downloadFile = (data: { id: string }) =>
  axios
    .get<Blob>(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/file/${data.id}/download`, {
      responseType: 'blob',
    })
    .then((res: AxiosResponse<Blob>) => {
      console.log('res', res);
      let filename = 'file';
      const contentDisposition = res.headers['content-disposition'];
      if (contentDisposition) {
        const filenameMatch = contentDisposition.match(
          /filename="?(.+?)"?(\;|$)/
        );
        if (filenameMatch.length > 1) {
          filename = filenameMatch[1];
        }
      }

      return {
        data: res.data,
        filename: filename,
      };
    });


Unfortunately, the data in response is and empty object {} and I can't download file. What might be the reason? In backed the buffer looks fine:
<Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0a 25 d3 eb e9 e1 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 2f 54 69 74 6c 65 20 28 4d 61 74 68 57 69 7a 61 72 64 73 29 0a 2f 43 72 65 ... 101467 more bytes>

========================================================================================================================================

You can fix this in one of two ways:

Ensure that the response header set is accurate.
Use red.send to send the buffer instead of res.end.

